# Program reports exceptions when not using try and catch

Tags: java, cryptography, try-catch, bufferedreader

I'm still very new to java and I'm working on a school assignment that's working on cryptography. When I was searching for methods to read from files I saw many had a try and catch block. I'm not very familiar with the use of these and I want to try and avoid using them in my code but when I remove them I have two exceptions reported at the new in `new FileReader` and at the bracket after `reader.readLine()`. But if I do use them it works relatively well. Can anyone explain what is happening? Also when using the catch and try I get an exception Null when my encoding is done. Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Encrypter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File input = null;
        if (1 < args.length) {
            input = new File(args[1]);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Invalid arguments count:" + args.length);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        String key = args[0];
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            int i = 0;
            String[] inputText = new String[20];
            String[] encryptText = new String[20];
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));
            while ((inputText[i] = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                encryptText[i] = inputText[i];
                System.out.println(inputText[i]);
                ++i;
            }
            int hash = key.hashCode();
            Random random = new Random(hash);
            String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ";
            String alphabetPerm = alphabet;
            char temp;
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                int n1 = random.nextInt(27) + 0;
                int n2 = random.nextInt(27) + 0;
                char[] swapper = alphabet.toCharArray();
                temp = swapper[n1];
                swapper[n1] = swapper[n2];
                swapper[n2] = temp;
                String alphaSwap = new String(swapper);
                alphabet = alphaSwap;
            }
            System.out.println(alphabet);
            for (int k = 0; k < inputText.length; k++) {
                encryptText[k] = inputText[k].replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+", " ");
                for (int j = 0; j < inputText[k].length(); j++) {
                    int index = alphabetPerm.indexOf(encryptText[k].charAt(j));
                    encryptText[k] = alphabetSwapper(encryptText[k], alphabet, index, j);
                    System.out.println(encryptText[k]);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Caught Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static String alphabetSwapper(String s, String alpha, int index, int value) {
        char toSwap = s.charAt(value);
        char[] inputChars = s.toCharArray();
        inputChars[value] = alpha.charAt(index);
        String swapped = new String(inputChars);
        return swapped;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are better off not catching the exception the way you are because you are discarding the two most useful pieces of information, which exception was thrown and where did it happen.

Instead of catching the exception, you can add the exceptions to the `throws` clause of `main()`

e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // ...
}
```

> Can anyone explain what is happening?

When you read a file you might be an `IOException` e.g. if the file is not present. You might have to catch this exception but for now you can let the caller to `main` print it out if it happens.

> Also when using the catch and try I get an exception Null when my encoding is done

This means you are triggering an exception without a message. If you print the exception and where it happened(or let the JVM do it for you) you will see where.

To determine why this is happening I suggest stepping through the code in your debugger so you can understand what each line does.

Answer (score 0):

A main method of the form as you pasted is usually the entry point of a program and not called by other java code. So it is good practise to catch and handle all Exceptions before leaving your program.

'Handle' can mean different things:

1. Simply print the message of the exception to the console as you do (in that case you loose information as Peter Lawrey already pointed out).
2. Print the stacktrace (e.printStackStrace()) which outputs more information about the exception on the stderr output. This is what java does if the main() method is left with an uncaught exception.
3. If using a logger framework: Loggers and its Appenders are able to print all exception information into a destination of your choice.
4. Handle it (1-3) and exit java with an exit code != 0 in order that a (programmatical) caller of your application can handle the error situation.

BTW1: I even would catch Throwable. So you also catch possible unchecked exceptions (NullPointerException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, etc.). And place the try at the very beginning (if you make an error in accessing your args array you would have covered also the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)

BTW2: If you would **not** have any try..catch in the main method I assume the code would not even compile because the compiler can detect that there might be unhandled checked exceptions (from your IO operations).

Comment: Yea my code will only compile using try/catch or putting `throw IOException` in the main method. I'm just curious as to what in this code causes exceptions, is it the fact that i'm utilizing `BufferedReader` or manipulating files? I've never had to use either before.

Comment: Every input- or outputstream formally declares checked IOExceptions (or derivations) on its main methods. Since the concept is very broad a stream can read from nearly everything which is a simple sequence of bytes: Files, byte arrays, socket lines, etc. During operations on these resources many failures can happen which is signaled through a thrown exception.

Comment: Readers and Writers are just thin wrappers around another stream. On Readers and writers you operate with strings (character sequences) whereas on streams you operate with pure byte or byte array. Therefore - when working with Readers and Writers - the indication of the characterset to be used is important (in order to define the translation of byte array into characters)